# Background image not applying on codepen

Tags: image, background-image, codepen

I am having a problem with my background image on codepen not showing up. It was fine at first and then one day the background just showed up as white.

Here is the link to my codepen `(https://codepen.io/Dylanidas/pen/QgOPdQ)`. I've tried setting the image inline with the body tag of the HTML, I've tried using http and https for the image link. I've also tried hosting the image on imgur, google photos, and dropbox to no avail. I was thinking it might have been a problem with the hosting sites but nothing I do seems to work. Also I have already looked at the past posts about this question and those didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to use the absolute path from Imgur. It is labeled direct link as opposed to absolute path.